# Page load order for back button cache

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser

After posting a form, and then using a browser back button to return to the page, how does the page load?

In particular:

- What state of the page is cached (initial or posted)?
- Does the page reload, with scripts, in the same order?
- What form post data is reloaded into the page fields?
- And at what point in the page load are the form post data fields repopulated?

Is there any standard documentation on how browsers should handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Depends on the browser
- Loads either from cache or from downloading just like loading a page any other time
- Depends on the browser if the the inputs stay filled in or not
- Usually `onload`, but it depends on the browser

The forward/back buttons are not part of the W3C spec. You may want to search for "handling the back button" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the forward and back buttons are completely browser-dependent. For example, Internet Explorer will expire a page (and force reload) if the page's expiration header has passed, but Firefox will not. 
Firefox will retain what the user's form data, (cache the "posted" state of the page) but Internet Explorer will not.